# Concave/Convex function second derivative and graph

Tags: calculus

Let’s say we have $g(x)=(1+x)e^{-x}$.

Therefore, $g''(x)=(x-1)e^{-x}$

So, normally, we can tell that $g(x)$ is concav between $\left[-\infty;1 \right]$ and convex elsewhere.

But when I look at the shape of the function on wolfram, I see it as a concave function.

Can anybody help ?

Regards,

Comment: Plot it more carefully. The $x \ge 1$ part of the graph is probably squashed because of the exponential growth for $x <0$.

Comment: I cannot plot it in any other way, this is from Wolfram. Moreover, for $x<1$, the function is concav, not convex, so the growth is not exponential. I don't understand.

Comment: First, you have $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and it does so 'very quickly'. Second, when you plot it, the negative part will dominate the plot visually, so you will have a hard time distinguishing the convex part. Try plotting for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: You are correct, it is concave on $(-\infty, 1]$ and convex on $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check whether it is concave to the origin or not!!

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me. I have to consider concavity/convexity over the overall domain, not only at 0. Right ?

Comment: Yeah I know what I am saying that at $x=-1$ the graph cuts the x axis. So what can you say concavity & convexity below $ x $ axis and above $x$ axis?

Comment: @user152715: What does the x axis have to do with anything?

Comment: I am asked to tell if this function is concav, convex, or neither of it. I would tell neither, but it is not what I am saying

Comment: I am saying that your mathematical calculation is perfect. But the conclusion from Wolfram is not ok.

Comment: @user152715 We are interested in where $g''= 0$, not where $g$ is zero! And that's at $x=1$ $$g'' = 0 \iff x = 1$$

Comment: ok thanks for your help